# How to use word hyperlinks?

Tags: firefox, openoffice.org, desktop-environments

When I open word document in Open Office I have link like this
https://somehome/someword.doc#SOME_SECTION

I think it should work that when I click on the link its forwarded to SOME_SECTION in that document. However the link is opened in firefox and document is opened without focus on SOME_SECTION. Is there any way to use that function on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#SOME_SECTION` will only work if there is an appropriate anchor in the document. HTML has the `<a name="anchor-name"></a>`. In the .doc file there should be anchors as well.

You may need to insert an empty link first and then make it into an anchor by filling in the "name" field.